# "Headphones plugged in" when that's not the case

Tags: 18.04, sound, 19.04, headphones, speakers

I tried this with Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04, it even happens when booting from an installation media.

---

Basically, when there's no headphones plugged in, the system thinks they are plugged in and the sound is (probably) sent to the headphone jack, so there's no sound from the speakers.

When I plug in headphones, the system says headphones are unplugged, and sound comes from the speakers. No sound through headphones.

I already force audio output to my headphones with pavucontrol and mute the speakers with alsamixer, but it's annoying to select it every time.

I want the system to recognize it correctly. Can someone help me?

---

`alsactl restore` doesn't help

Just in case, I have a Thinkpad E485 which needs 2 kernel parameters to run:
`ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0
spec_store_bypass_disable=prctl`

https://medium.com/@jthegedus/ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e485-15e1d601473f